# How i can embed a session_id(); to a Flashfile?

Tags: php, html, flash

i tried to give a swf file a sessionid but it dont works just in IE, anyone have a idea whats wrong?

```
            <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="650" height="430" id="upload" align="middle">
                    <param name="movie" value="upload.swf?PHPSESSID=<? print session_id(); ?>" FlashVars="PHPSESSID=<? print session_id(); ?>" />
<param name="flashvars" value="PHPSESSID=<? print session_id(); ?>">
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="upload.swf"  width="650" height="430">
                    <param name="movie" value="upload.swf?PHPSESSID=<? print session_id(); ?>" FlashVars="PHPSESSID=<? print session_id(); ?>" />
<param name="flashvars" value="PHPSESSID=<? print session_id(); ?>">
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                    <param name="play" value="true" />
                    <param name="loop" value="true" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                    <param name="menu" value="true" />
                    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                    <param name="salign" value="" />

                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--<![endif]-->
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
```

Comment: It would be useful to paste the actual source code from the IE window, to see how the php code is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

the code for !IE is not right.
the parameters should written into the tag,
like this:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="upload.swf"  width="650" height="430" flashvars="PHPSESSID=<? print session_id(); ?>"></object>
```

Other paramters should be process in the same way.

Comment: this dont work too :( i've tried now all other Browsers and it just works in IE.